# ios9 cache for NSData?

Tags: swift, caching, uiimage, ios9, nsdata

I use the following code to display UIImage loaded from Internet:

```
let imgURLString = "http://.../images/" + (self.userImage as String)
let imgURL = NSURL(string: imgURLString)
let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL!)
self.profilePictureImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
```

That works good with the iphone5 simulator if the image is not too big.

But when I test it with my phone (ios9 iphone5), if I change the image on the server, the old image is still displayed.

I think there is a cache.

Is there a way to clear the cache? Or maybe a better approach to display images stored on a remote server?

Thank you for your feedback.

Regards,

Thomas

**EDIT**

I just found one interesting thing.

When I test in local network (through WIFI), it works fine with both simulator and iPhone.

But When I test remotely (through 4G), the image displayed is the old image. I have to connect the server with a web browser and refresh the images folder to make the new image display on the app.

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: When you change the image on the server, does the iOS app reconnects properly to get the new image? You might want to check that. Because although `UIImage(named: )` caches, `UIImage(data: )` doesn't.

Comment: What do you mean by "reconnects properly to get the new image"?

Because all the code to set up the image when the profile view is loaded is above.

Comment: he means, do you load the image again after changing the image on the server.

Comment: Yes, I even killed and started again the app but the old image is still displayed.

Comment: After few minutes waiting, the new image is correctly displayed when I launch again the app. And I repeat, with the simulator I do not have this issue.

Comment: Are you having error messages of any kind?

Comment: No I do not have any error messages or something trouble.

Comment: Ok I think I am close to get it. First, the issue is here even with the simutor. Secondly, when I change the image on the server and want to check it with my Web browser, I see the old image and I need to refresh one time to see the new image. And then, it works on the app, the new image is displayed. So I think there is a cache on my server side (simple Apache Web server). Any idea to resolve it?

Comment: I just edit my post after other finds.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it by changing the name of the new image stored on the remote server. Thus, I avoid any caching issue.